# Adding and editing a JSON array in Watson Assistant

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, artificial-intelligence, ibm-watson

I'm learning Watson AI / Assistant for my company since we intend to pitch it to clients (we're a web dev firm). I got into the assistant and am teaching myself it by designing a text adventure game. In this game, Watson is leading you through a world in which you can pick things up and put them down and that sort of thing. So I'm trying to get watson to create a JSON array called an inventory.

However, while I managed to create the array under the context variable option, I can't add or subtract to it easily as there doesn't appear to be a way for my Assistant to execute any code.

My question is pretty simple: can I, on recognition of an intent, execute javascript code? For example, if the user types "pick up sand" where the intent is "pick up" and sand is the entity that's recognized, then execute javascript to parse the entity result (sand) into the array "inventory"?

Is this possible?

I have tried creating the context variable as an array (works). However, I can't update it without printing the whole thing which makes it useless as an array and an inventory. Here's the JSON array I create with a context variable addition at the first step.

```
    {
      "output": {
        "generic": [
          {
            "values": [
              {
                "text": "Welcome to Kojoto."
              }
            ],
            "response_type": "text",
            "selection_policy": "sequential"
          },
          {
            "time": 5000,
            "typing": false,
            "response_type": "pause"
          }
        ]
      },
      "context": {
        "Inventory": [
          {
            "name": "belt",
            "description": "A leather belt."
          },
          {
           "name": "pouch",
            "description": "A leather pouch."
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I want to be able, on a recognized intent, to add to the inventory without removing the whole array. This way it's incredibly more efficient and usable than shifting $has-sand from "yes" to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood you want to add and delete an object to the array.

Take a look at the following methods which can help you add an object in the array if any intent is matched also you can delete it the same way.

**[JSONArray.append(object)](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-arrays-append) :**

```
{
  "context": {
    "toppings_array": "<? $toppings_array.append('ketchup', 'tomatoes') ?>"
  }
}
```

Appends a new value to the JSONArray

**[JSONArray.remove(Integer)](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-arrays-remove) :**

```
{
  "context": {
    "toppings_array": "<? $toppings_array.remove(0) ?>"
  }
}
```

Removes the element in the index position from the JSONArray

[List of complete methods](http://%20https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-arrays)

Comment: This is super helpful, thanks! Do you know how this append would be applied to work with a nested array  (with params)? Such as appending this `{ "name":"Sand", "color":"blue" }` to an array that contains those qualities.
I can't get it to work, the quotations cause it to fail. I don't know SpEL all that well and the guides I found outside of IBM do not contain this information.